# Ticking time in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, timer

I have a label and timer inside update panel which is also inside script manager. The timer interval was 1000 milliseconds. The label must return the current system date and time and it should be ticking. I used below codes and its working. It returns the current date and time and its ticking too, but the problem is the second/s that ticks skips some seconds. For example: the current time is 09:11:17, after a tick it becomes 09:11:20, it skips 2 seconds.

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If Not IsPostBack Then
          Label2.Text = Date.Now.ToString
    End If

End Sub

 Protected Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick

    Label2.Text = Date.Now.ToString

End Sub
```

What must be the problem in this case?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't trust the scheduler to work exactly every second. Lower your update rate to something like 500 ms

Comment: I tried it sir but seconds still skips

Comment: Can you show your markup as well